# NSError and Error in Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling, nserror, do-catch

I've seen that there is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179441/whats-the-difference-between-error-and-nserror-in-swift) on the difference between `NSError` and `Error` in Swift and I am aware of the differences. However, I do not understand the behavior of the code snippet below, since it compiles correctly. Swift's error handling mechanism requires that every do-catch block not appearing in a function with a throws clause to include one generic handler (either `catch` with nothing else or a `catch` for Error). However, it appears that using `NSError` has the same effect. Does anybody here know the reason why? I've read in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071160/swift-should-nserror-now-be-considered-as-legacy) that "any ErrorType-conformant class can be casted to NSError. These features are described here in the docs.". However, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10) pointed to by that answer did not clarify this point to me, since it focuses on Objective-C, which I am not using.

```
import Foundation
extension Int : Error {}
extension String : Error {}

func fErr() throws {
  let a = Int(readLine()!)!
  if a > 20 {
    throw 42
  } else {
    throw "An error occurred"
  }
}

func gErr() {
  do {
    try fErr()
  } catch let e as NSError {
    print(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

On Darwin platforms (macOS, iOS, tvOS, watchOS), Swift has a concept called [bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) which allows Swift types offered by the standard library to *bridge* to Objective-C types (usually vended by the Cocoa frameworks). Types which do this include

- `Array` ↔︎ `NSArray`
- `Dictionary` ↔︎ `NSDictionary`
- `Set` ↔︎ `NSSet`
- `Error` ↔︎ `NSError`
- etc. (see the above link for a more comprehensive list)

Bridging types requires compiler support, and the `Error` ↔︎ `NSError` bridging has [quite](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a716d403d62a512ae37fc5f2122cd4a559a17b3a/include/swift/AST/KnownFoundationEntities.def) [a few](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a912a12805e5f99f177f7f6a90bfa8f1d3913847/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift) [components](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Sema/DerivedConformanceError.cpp) ([among others](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c12a25d0fe887d81ddefcbdf846927aba0d76752/lib/SILGen/SILGen.h)). This bridging, though, allows the compiler to generally treat `NSError`s as `Error`s and vice versa; in fact, as you can see in the snippet above, *any* `Error` can be cast to an `NSError` and back.

You can see some of the runtime components needed to make this happen in [another answer of mine on custom `NSError`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48344928/adopting-customnserror-in-decodingerror/48345281#48345281), but the gist is that any `Error` can provide enough information to be wrapped up in an `NSError` instance (by implementing `var _domain`, `var _code`, and `var _userInfo`), and vice versa.

When you catch an error `as NSError`, you implicitly bridge the `Error` (no matter what it is) into an `NSError`, in the same way that you can bridge `[1, 2, 3] as NSArray` or `["foo" : "bar"] as NSDictionary`.

[Note that bridging is currently only available where the Objective-C runtime is available, i.e. only on Darwin platforms. Such bridging calls do not work on Linux.]

See also [SE-0112 Improved NSError Bridging](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md) (the original Swift Evolution proposal) for more background on this and further detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer thorough answer. The part about bridging calls not working on Linux really caught my attention. Gonna test it.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see there is an implicit conversion somewhere of the Swift source code.

One of the possible proofs is this part of C++ [code](https://github.com/apple/swift/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ErrorToNSErrorFn&type=)
 `Optional<SILDeclRef> ErrorToNSErrorFn;`